# How to put main breaker in Square D Hom612L100 breaker panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

This panel (Square D Hom612L100) has 4 slots.  Is it possible to make one of them serve as the main breaker?

Comment: Six, but it's still a cripplingly small panel.  People always want more power later, so you're better off using a much larger panel (12/16?) for versatility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do this, but it burns up two panel spaces in the process

While the HOM612L100 is a Main Lug Only panel and thus cannot accept a QOM *main frame* breaker, it *can* be fitted with a main breaker.  How?  By *backfeeding* the panel's busses via a two-pole Homeline branch breaker that is *held down* with a HOM1RK hold-down kit, as required by NEC 408.36.  As a result, the incoming hot wires go onto the lugs of this held-down breaker, and the main lugs can be left unused, or used as feed-through lugs in case expansion is called for.

Note that this requires the main breaker to be a regular (or triplex/quadruplex) Homeline branch breaker, *not* a GFCI or AFCI (they cannot be backfed as it would damage their electronics), and also costs two panel spaces in what is already a tiny panel; depending on your application, moving up to say a 12-space panel that accepts a main frame breaker may be a better solution as a result.

Answer (score -2):

If it's the same as [what I'm seeing on Home Depot's website](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-100-Amp-6-Space-12-Circuit-Indoor-Flush-Mount-Main-Lug-Load-Center-with-Cover-No-Door-HOM612L100FCP/100149777), I'm going to say no.

A main would serve to cut power to the hot busses in the panel. As I can't actually see what the inner parts of the panel look like, I'm inclined to say that it's probably just an always-on sort of thing. If you want a main for it, get a service disconnect to go between that panel and the utility feed.

Comment: This is actually *incorrect*

Comment: Care to elaborate? Rather than just blatantly calling it wrong, some constructive detail would be beneficial for everyone.

Comment: see my answer for details. the TL;DR is that the panel will let you backfeed a branch breaker, turning it into a main